# trace method execution in scala

Tags: python, scala

If I want to trace method execution in Python I would implement the following decorator:

```
def trace(f):
    indent = '   '
    def _f(*args):
        signature = '%s(%s)' % (f.__name__, ', '.join(map(repr, args)))
        print '%s--> %s' % (trace.level*indent, signature)
        trace.level += 1
        try:
            result = f(*args)
            print '%s<-- %s == %s' % ((trace.level-1)*indent, signature, result)
        finally:
            trace.level -= 1
        return result
    trace.level = 0
    return _f

def disabled(f) : return f

# uncomment the following line to disable tracing
# trace = disabled
```

Then I can decorate methods I want to trace:

```
@trace
def my_method(arg1, arg2):
...
```

Another possibility would be to use [a trace module](http://docs.python.org/library/trace.html).

What are idiomatic ways to trace method execution in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

A function decorator in Python is just syntactic sugar for saying `my_method = trace(my_method)`.  Since Scala also supports first-class functions, you could actually do the same thing.

There is one catch, however.  Since Python is untyped, it doesn't matter what the type signature of the function is.  Scala cares about this.  You could get around the problem a bit because Scala has a function trait for each argument-list arity: `Function0` through `Function22`.  Other people might have better ideas, but you could write a `trace` method for each function type (or one trace method that has a big `match` in it) and and then call your functions through the trace method.  You only need to worry about the number of arguments since you can use generics to ignore their types.